# how to do date and time sort in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

here I want to sort data according to date and time both are in string type first I am converting string in date but time is stored in other column like "10:30" or "16:45" and date is in "25.6.2018" format. so how to do sort for both date and time.

as shown in query sordorder has 1 or -1 and it is done for date but I also want it for time

```
 collection.aggregate([{
   $addFields: { preParationDateCustome: { $dateFromString: { dateString: "$preparationDate", format: "%d.%m.%Y" } } }
},sortOperator])
```

```
 sortactive = "preParationDateCustome";
 var sortOperator = { "$sort": {} },
 sort = sortactive;
sortOperator["$sort"][sort] = sortorder;
```

I want my table as shown in image[image]

Comment: Can you give an example of what your documents look like?

Comment: Are the time values in the input document  formatted as `"9:30"` _or_ `"09:30"`?

Comment: it is store as "09:30"

Comment: You can use the aggregation stage: `{ $sort: { preParationDateCustom: 1, timeField: 1 } }` to do the sorting (after the `$addFields` stage in the aggregation).

Answer (score 0):

So let's start off by inserting some documents with some string dates and times based on your formation

```js
db.test.insertMany([
    {date: "1.6.2018", time: "09:00"},       
    {date: "15.6.2018", time: "09:00"},
    {date: "1.6.2018", time: "09:30"},
    {date: "15.6.2018", time: "09:30"},
    {date: "15.6.2018", time: "12:00"},
    {date: "15.6.2018", time: "12:30"},
    {date: "25.6.2018", time: "09:00"},
    {date: "1.6.2018", time: "12:00"},
    {date: "25.6.2018", time: "09:30"},
    {date: "25.6.2018", time: "12:00"},
    {date: "25.6.2018", time: "12:30"},
    {date: "1.6.2018", time: "12:30"}
]);
```

after we've got this inserted we can then use an aggregation query to convert our string datetimes in to in dates then sort them.

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields:{
            date: {
                $dateFromString: {
                    dateString: { $concat: [ "$date", " ", "$time" ] },
                    format: "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unset: "time"
    },
    {
        $sort : { "date" : 1 }
    }
]);
```

This uses a [$dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) expression to convert our strings into dates then we just sort them.